# ubuntu 16.04 and three monitors

Tags: nvidia, integrated

I've got nvidia geforce gt 730 which supports only two monitors but I thought about using an integrated card. Is that even possible? I have enabled the card in BIOS but after connecting it I can only see black screen (not even 'no signal' or something like that message).

I've got Gigabyte B85M-D3H-A.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible since B85 supports Intel FDI (Flexible Display Interface), but you may have to resort to using the nouveau drivers.